Cloud Gateway Max serves internet to any devices connected, but doesn't connect itself
I configured my Ubiquiti Cloud Gateway Max as a PPPoE modem using the settings my ISP gave me, which were just the username/password and an VLAN id. All devices connected to the network through the Cloud Gateway have internet, but the Cloud Gateway does not see the internet.
I have tried rebooting, configuring the DNS of the internet to 1.1.1.1 rather than the default and even ssh'd into it. In SSH I ran echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1" > /etc/resolv.conf and then tested by pinging 1.1.1.1, and received this result:
root@CloudGatewayMax:~# ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
534 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 554288ms

dpinger returns this:
root@CloudGatewayMax:~# Resolving ping.ui.com
ping.ui.com: Alarm latency 0us stddev 0us loss 0.0000%, target not resolved

Topology of the network is:
Fiber from network -> Black box from network -> ethernet -> Cloud Gateway Max -> rest of network.
What else should I try?
